# Is it possible to assign return value from two higher order functions to the same variable in Python?[see details]

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

There is a tutorial at http://pythonprogramming.jottit.com/functional_programming and it gives an example how to use higher order functions to return functions:

```
def trace(f):
    f.indent = 0
    def g(x):
        print '|  ' * f.indent + '|--', f.__name__, x
        f.indent += 1
        value = f(x)
        print '|  ' * f.indent + '|--', 'return', repr(value)
        f.indent -= 1
        return value
    return g
```

and

```
def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    def g(x):
        if x not in cache:
            cache[x] = f(x)
        return cache[x]
    return g
```

but I don't get how it's able to assign two functions on the same variable on the statements:

```
fib = trace(fib)
fib = memoize(fib)
print fib(4)
```

both trace and memoize seem to have effect on the last call. Why is that?

Comment: "both trace and memoize seem to have effect on the last call" They've both been called. Any more questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `trace()` and `memoize()` create a new function object and return it to you.

In each case, the new function object "wraps" the old function object, so the original function is not lost.

Using my amazing ASCII art skills, here is a diagram:

```
f(x)   # this is your original function

trace(f(x))   # trace "wraps" it and returns a wrapped object

memoize(trace(f(x)))   # memoize "wraps" it and returns a new wrapped function object
```

We start out with a function object bound to the name `fib`.

Then we call `trace(fib)` which creates a new function object.  When it is first created, its name is `g` but we then bind it to the name `fib`.  Try printing `fib.__name__`.

Then we call `memoize(fib)` which creates a new function object.  Again it's first created with the name of `g` but then bound to the name `fib`.

Remember, in Python everything is an object, and objects can exist with no name, with one name, or with many names.  In this case, we keep re-using the name `fib` but we keep re-binding it with different function objects.

Answer (score 3):

What you've written is very similar to

```
fib2 = memoize(trace(fib))
print fib2(4)
```

because you have changed which function the variable `fib` points to after the call to `trace`, so `memoize` is applied to the tracing version (and then `fib` is "overwritten" again).

If you want to have a tracing version and a memoized version separately, you need to assign their results to different variables, e.g.:

```
fib_trace = trace(fib)
fib_memo = memoize(fib)
print fib_trace(4), fib_memo(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's no different than:

```
a = a + 2
a = a + 5
print a
```

Just as `a` will have increased by 7, `fib` will have had both decorators applied to it.

Comment: Sorry @Ignacio the above analogy feels different from the question for me. In your case a is 'overwritten' by a new value; I doesn't get something more. Perhaps I have to read on decorators. I thought both functions were generating new ones and fib would be overwritten on the second assignment. Can you tell me what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: `fib` is being overwritten. That they have a reference to the object that fib *used* to contain is just fluff.

Comment: How does it perform both jobs(trace, memoize) then?

Comment: "It" doesn't. The wrappers in the decorators do.